# State inside self-hosted WCF service being lost with InstanceContextMode.Single

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, self-hosting

I am using WCF service and self hosting it as not everything is contained within the service itself (some external events are happening outside of the service):

1. WCF Service and I am self hosting it in a C# Console App. When WCF clients conncet they call the Login function, and I (try!) to store their callback via `GetCallbackChannel`
2. 3rd party DLL which calls my console back via a delegate on a different thread from the library
3. On this console callback I then call in to the WCF service who pool which is then passed on to the WCF service who then broadcasts to all connected clients via a callback contract.

All is fine with the client connecting, calling Login, and I save the callback interface object.

However when I access the code from my service, i find it is an entirely new object and my _endPointMap is empty (despite me storing it in the Login method which is called by the client):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service : IService, IEndpointNotifier
{
    public readonly TwoWayDictionary<string, IClientCallback> _endpointMap = new TwoWayDictionary<string, IClientCallback>();

    // called by WCF client when they click the login button - it works
    public void Login(string username)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext
            .Current
            .GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();

        _endpointMap.AddOrUpdate(username, callback);
        list.Add(username);
    }

    // called by the WCF self-host console app
    public void IEndpointNotifier.Notify(string info, string username)
    {
        // at this point my list _endpointMap is empty despite
        // having received a Login previously and adding to the
        // list. so i am unable to call my clients back!!

        _endPointMap.Count(); // is 0 at this point?!!
    }
}
```

My main console app starts up the service fine also as below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var service = new Service();
    var host = new ServiceHost(service);

    // between the above line and the task below calling
    // service.Notify I click a number of times on client
    // which calls the Login method

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            // at this point, service seems like a new object?!
            // any data saved in the list member will be lost,
            // and will only see the single entry from time of
            // construction

            service.Notify("hi","bob");
        }
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Questions please**

1. The object seems totally different to the one that was modified in a previous operation (on login from client) - is there any way to tell what service object I am actually looking at (equivalent to the old C++ days and looking at the address pointer for `this`)?
2. The singleton attribute seems to be ignored `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]` Any ideas what I am doing wrong (why the internal list variable keeps getting reset)?
3. The WCF service cannot be self contained. How does one achieve communication between WCF self-hosted app and the WCF service according to best practice or is this abusing WCF and what is was designed for (when considering scopes etc)?
4. I set the breakpoint in the constructor with some dummy values. That breakpoint is only ever hit the first time when i construct it. When i go in to the object via the service.Notify method although the object seems new (members are empty) the constructor breakpoint is not hit - how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why the values were not being saved... my WCF client proxy was connecting to the VS WCF Service Host and not my host in the code!

I noticed this when I saw the WCF Service Host running in the service bar tray.

I disabled WCF Service Host starting up for the WCF .svc service by right clicking on the `WCF Project` -> `Properties` -> `WCF Options` -> unticked `Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution`

Answer (score 1):

I have hosted the 3rd party app behind a static global member variable that I control.  So I am responsible for all communication and state and cleanup between the 3rd party lib and the normal wcf calls.  I am responsible for thread lifetimes for the 3rd party app.  If I create them I have to close them.  Holding references in my own lists.

It is like it is a separate app but they just happen to be in the same process space.  All communication to and from the 3rd party app is controlled by me formally.

You will probably need a thread that looks for completed or abandoned 3rd party objects after usage to kill them your self outside of normal wcf msg processing.

This lets the wcf part be a normal threaded (thread pool) concept with no special declarations.

side note:
I would take out the loop and make it two lines in your simple model.

service.Notify("hi")
   Console.ReadLine();

This will expose your object lifetime details instead hiding them for 3 seconds.